# How to mock a global variable in a class

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I have a class file, `someClass.js` that looks like:

```
//assigns globalVar from some file
const globalVar = getFromFile() //returns a string such as "some global var"

export default class SomeClass {
  ...
  public static someFunc() {
     if (globalVar == "Hello"){
       return 2
     }
     else {
       return 3
     }
  }
```

And in my test file, I'm importing it as so:

```
import SomeClass from './someClass';
```

In my tests I want to overwrite the `globalVar` with different values for each test like this:

```
test('call someFunc with globalVar set to Hello', async () => {
  //set globalVar to "Hello"--how can I do this?
  const result = SomeClass.someFunc()
  expect(result).toBe(2)
}
```

How can I do this? Is there any way to mock a `const`?

Comment: i think is better to set the variable as class variable in the constructor

Comment: what `getFromFile` does return and where it comes from(separate file)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Const can not be altered, that's why it is called a constant.

Use var instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a 'Var' variable. The constant variable will be readonly :)

I recommend you taking a look at this: 
https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

As @Markus Zeller said you should use `var`.
Otherwise you can do something like this :

```
const globalvar = "Hello"

 class MyClass  {
  constructor(data=false) {
    this.globalVar  = !data ? globalvar : data;
  }

   someFunc() {
     if (this.globalVar == "Hello"){
       return 2
     }else {
       return 3
     }
   }
}

let myclass = new MyClass()
console.log(myclass.globalVar )
console.log(myclass.someFunc() )

var anotherglobalvar = "another var :D"
let anothermyclass = new MyClass(anotherglobalvar)
console.log(anothermyclass.someFunc() )
```

If no argument are passed to the constructor it uses the global `globalvar` else it will use the argument.

Answer (score -2):

Define the constants in a separated module and then mock it.